# how to rename and save extracted pages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extract, file-rename, getstaticpaths

I have a 28 page pdf file. I would like to create a button that allows me to extract page 5 and rename it before saving it in the documents folder.
With another button, I would like to email as an attachment page 5 renamed.
I created this function:

```js
var cToAddr = "apctr@example.com"
var cSubLine = "Paperwork"
var cBody = "Here is your paperwork."
var page0 = this.extractPages (5);
page0.mailDoc ({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});
page0.closeDoc (true);
app.execMenuItem("SaveAs", page0);
```

This feature works. I have solutions searched in the acrobat forums, but failed to create the correct "cPath" formula. This is the directory where I want to save the renamed page in pdf format "/ C / Users / User Name / Documents / QUESTION.pdf"
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you